# Get value from URLSession and pass to another view

Tags: swift, request, urlsession

I am quite new to Swift and I am trying to save a value from URLSession and pass it to another view.

Login Page > Generate Pass > Save it and Pass to the second view where it will be used for another URLSessions.

```
import SwiftUI

struct API_Success: Decodable{
    let result:API_Success_Result
}

struct API_Success_Result: Decodable{
    let sessionuuid:String
}

struct LoginView: View {
    
    @State private var username:String = ""
    @State private var gkpass:String = ""
    @State private var wrongUsername:Int = 0
    @State private var wrongGkpass:Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ZStack{
                Color.init(UIColor(red: 0.0/255, green: 48.0/255, blue: 63.0/255, alpha: 1.0))
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                Circle()
                    .scale(1.7)
                    .foregroundColor(.init(UIColor(red: 0.0/255, green: 123.0/255, blue: 116.0/255, alpha: 1.0)))
                Circle()
                    .scale(1.35)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                VStack{
                    Text("API")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .bold()
                        .padding()
                        .foregroundColor(.init(UIColor(red: 0.0/255, green: 48.0/255, blue: 63.0/255, alpha: 1.0)))
                    TextField("Username", text: $username)
                        .padding()
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
                        .background(Color.black.opacity(0.05))
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .border(.red, width: CGFloat(wrongUsername))
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    SecureField("App Password", text: $gkpass)
                        .padding()
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
                        .background(Color.black.opacity(0.05))
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .border(.red, width: CGFloat(wrongGkpass))
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    Button("Log In"){
                        //Login Action
                        requestSessionUUID(username: username.lowercased(), gkpass: gkpass.lowercased(), sessionuuid: { (sessionuuid) in
                            print(sessionuuid)
                        })

                    }
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
                        .background(Color.init(UIColor(red: 0.0/255, green: 48.0/255, blue: 63.0/255, alpha: 1.0)))
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                }
            }.navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
    
    func requestSessionUUID(username: String, gkpass: String, sessionuuid: @escaping (String) -> Void){
        
        let url = URL(string: "https://example.com")!
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        
        .
        .
        .
        
        let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: [])
        
        request.httpBody = jsonData
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            // Check for Errors
            if error == nil , data != nil{
                
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                do{
                    let parsedData = try decoder.decode(API_Success.self, from: data!)
                    sessionuuid(parsedData.result.sessionuuid)
                } catch{
                    print("Error while Parsing!")
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LoginView()
    }
}
```

I am able to print the sessionuuid but that's it. Can you please advise on how I can save it and pass it further?

The request and parsing work.

Maybe I am going on it from the wrong side.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a login state boolean in your viewModel class like this

```
@Published var loginState :Bool = false
```

in response success change the loginState to true

and in your SwiftUI file as your button action use navigationLink

```
var loginButton: some View {
            #if os(iOS)
            return NavigationLink(destination: <YourDestinationView>), isActive: $viewModel.loginState) {

}
```